# pivot_table and period_index for time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pivot-table

I have a dataset that I would like to prepare for visualization as time series data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('mypath.xlsx', usecols=['Account', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'])

df

Account Jan Feb Mar
0   300 NaN NaN NaN
1   310 -33 -33 -33
2   320  10   5   7
```

Now I'd like to pivot this dataframe to have the Account column as top row and ideally the Months (Jan, Feb, Mar) as index and converted to a period_index, so I can calculate time deltas and so on.

So I do this:

```
df = df.pivot_table(df, columns = ['Account'], fill_value = 0)

Account 300 310 320 
Feb       0 -33   5
Jan       0 -33  10
Mar       0 -33   7
```

How could I make Jan, Feb, Mar to be a period_index and act like an actual index in this example?

#############################

Solution to get a period_index is as follows:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime('2018-' + df.index)
print(idx)

[OUT]
DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Now converting to a period_index format

```
df.index = idx.to_period(freq='M')
print(df.index)

[OUT]
PeriodIndex(['2018-02', '2018-01', '2018-03'], dtype='period[M]', freq='M')
```

Eventually it looks like this:

```
Account 300 310 320 
2018-02   0 -33   5
2018-01   0 -33  10
2018-03   0 -33   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply modify your index as -

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime('2018-' + df.index)
```

So if your row indexes are in jumbled order as depicted in the question...then also you can convert it into pandas datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html#pandas-date-range) + [`Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html#pandas-index-map)

```
df.index = (
    df.index.map({v.strftime("%b") : v for v in pd.date_range("2018-01", "2018-03", freq="MS")})
)

df.index
Out[617]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: This solution actually also works perfectly fine. The above is just shorter, hence I chose that as a solution. Hope it's fine for you.